# How to resume last state (history nodes)

Tags: xstate

I'm learning x-state and I'm overwhelmed about its functionality, but I'm having issues understanding `history` nodes.

I'm creating a state which should hold the execution of the machine until an action is triggered:

[image: machine model]

So if the machine is in `AwaitingEmployeeSignature` or `AwaitingOnboardingCompletion`, and the `EA_REDLINED` event is triggered, I want to move the machine to the `Paused` state. But after a `RESUME` event (which is not implemented), I want to resume the last state `AwaitingEmployeeSignature` or `AwaitingOnboardingCompletion`, depending on what was the state before the `Paused` state

As I understand history nodes, it can achieve what I want, but as far as I understood, it doesn't hold this state, but when on it, it automatically moves to the last state (which is not what I want). How can I stay in the `Paused` state, and only move to the previous state when the `RESUME` event is triggered?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A history node targets the most recently visited child state of a parent state *before* exiting that parent state.

In your case, the solution would be to place the top 5 states in your diagram in some parent state, add a history state to that parent state, and on resume, transition to that e.g. `parent.hist` state.

Then the target of that resume event will be the last state that the parent state was in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this implementation. I'm really impressed with x-state, we are using it as a POC in a big tech company. If all goes well, we plan to use it as the new standard :)

Comment: @OtavioBonder did all went well?

Comment: I adopted another strategy, improving the transitions